# How come questions on SO get so few upvotes relative to some other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

Before I ever asked anything on SO itself, I was active on TeX.SX . My experience there is that valid questions, which are clear enough and not missing relevant data, most often get at least 1 up-vote; and that answer-providers often up-vote the question if it's a 0-vote or sometime even if it's a 1-vote question. You could say the logic is "if it's worthy of my reply, it's worthy of not being a zero-voter".

Now, TeX.SX is a much smaller site/community of users than SO itself. And yet, here, it seems that questions have a harder time getting any upvotes at all. Is this just my impression or is there more of an upvote stinginess in the SO culture? And, more importantly, is it not worthwhile to encourage voting over 0 as a means for 'vetting' a question?

**Edit**: See also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27675/196834) to the related question on [How come so few SO questions have an answer accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27660/196834).

Comment: SO gets a *lot* of questions, and we only have 40 upvotes each (fewer if we upvote some answers).

Comment: Less specialisation, lower influx of questions per topic == more focus *per question*. Stack Overflow is a veritable firehose, and we have only so many votes per day.

Comment: Questions move by quickly on SO. Questions on smaller sites stay on the first couple pages _much_ longer than on SO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But isn't that balanced by the high number of users (both experienced/high-reputation and inexperienced newbies)?

Comment: the quality of most questions is poor, unclear, and most of the time gets flagged and edited a couple of times before it becomes clear and understandable.

Comment: @mehow: I meant the ones with reasonable quality which don't get flagged.

Comment: @einpoklum: Try to follow the C#, PHP, Java or Python tags. The questions accumulate fast. You generally do *not* come back later and scan through the new questions accumulated so far, you only look at new ones coming in.

Comment: I like your question and I also have noticed that there are a small amount of upvotes! I think it takes a bit longer to answer a question than to put a question together(yea, even the good ones). Personally, I upvote any question that shows effort, is clear and i find it interesting even if its not within my interests. Same applies to the answers. Also, If i am ever looking for something and find it on SO, i will upvote it too since it resolves my issue(and saves time). You will see that most commonly asked questions will have a lot of upvotes. I dont wanna go off topic now so ill shut up:)

Comment: @mehow: It's not really off-topic... the slant in voting toward super-popular question is, I would say, the other side of the same problem. What use is there in taking a 127-vote question and making it 128? Certainly not much. I would say it's better to vote for low-vote questions, especially 0-vote ones. I might even comment on someone's flawed question, and if s/he improves it and replies to my comment I might go back and vote up.

Comment: FWIW: I downvote a lot :-)

Comment: @michaelb958: TeX.SX has the same limit... if you normalize by the number of users, it seems both sites are roughly the same.

Comment: Questions should never get upvoted. The only consideration is how many downvotes it deserves.

Comment: @user414076: Seriously?

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes.

Comment: @user414076: Ok, *why* should questions never be upvoted? (The designers of the site apparently didn't share your opinion.)

Comment: Every single question is a tax on those that must answer or moderate it. *Most* every question is a duplicate of something already answered. Or it's so heavily localized that nobody will find value in it beyond the asker. But the other strong opinion I have is that people ask too many questions, get too much rewards for asking them, when the **only** reward should be an *answer.* Give reputation and trust to the people who provide **answers.** The best that askers should hope for is to not have trust taken away. And yes, I'm serious.

Comment: @Keith I agree with the nameless user, in fact, I think the only vote you should be able to cast is a delete vote, albeit with a good motivation.

Comment: Consider the end result of the "there are no more good questions" approach: If it is our goal to moderate away almost every new question, eventually askers get tired and/or frustrated, new issues don't get presented, and the good answerers have no reason to stick around. The site dies. We should _encourage_ new, good questions, and moderate to remove the noise.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, I realize I'm mostly yelling at clouds and fighting a losing battle, I don't expect that many people agree with me, I know better than to expect anything to actually change. But I'm sick of seeing the same crap day after day, and the fact it's frankly easier and more rewarding to continue to spoon-fed these people rather than moderate and keep the site clean. So yall keep at it, enjoy yourselves, and I'll just continue to dial back participation (for my own sanity).

Comment: @user414076 Burnout is certainly understandable, so that may be the best approach for a time. I hope to see you back when you feel refreshed.

Comment: @user414076: This sounds a lot like "Everything that can be invented has been invented."  In fact, every time that Apple (or really anybody else for that matter) releases a new version of their OS, we get all kinds of new problems and questions that nobody has encountered before....

Comment: @lnafziger, I understand new tech will prompt new and incredibly useful questions. But I also understand that the C# tag has 80,000 questions titled "object reference not set to instance of object."

Comment: @user414076: While I respect your opinion, I wonder - do you think that it is popular enough to be, in part, the cause of the (perceived) relative lack of upvotes on SO?

Comment: @MartijnPieters and everyone else: Here's a case in point. A question of mine just became famous today, with 10,000 views. It only has 3 votes, 2 'favorite question' marks, and no down-votes. (My answer there, by the way, only has 1 vote.) So, I'm not saying this is the "bestest question ever" - but only 1 out of 10,000 people decided that this was a worthwhile question, for a question which is obviously of interest to many people and with which there's no fault which merited a downvote or a suggestion to amend (leaving the two 'favorite question' up-voters as outliers.)

Comment: That, or a google search for specific set of popular keywords includes that question in the results but it turns out to be irrelevant to what most of the searchers where looking for. Loads of views, but they all came to the wrong place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's possible, but the two-favorite-questions is an indication to the contrary. You would not expect to have votes/favorite-question-markers < 2, right?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram You seem to be saying that Stack Overflow would work best if it contained no questions at all.

Answer (score 4):

The number of questions asked every day makes a very big difference.

There are some active users browsing tags they are interested in. On smaller site there's a great chance they will eventually visit all questions asked in particular tags. On StackOverflow they will see only a tip of the iceberg.

Such active users are usually the most active voters.

Another factor is, that on each sites you have 30/40 votes a day. On smaller sites it's much more that the number of questions asked a day, making in theoretically possible to upvote (almost) all questions. On StackOverflow it's quite typical to be out of votes.

Comment: But shouldn't the number of questions be balanced out by the number of users? On SO there are a lot more knowledgeable users on all levels (1000+ rep, 10,000+ rep, 100,000+ rep...) ; seems to me everything should just scale.

Comment: But the mass makes it harder to browser good content, you're drown in the mass of new questions... Interesting phenomenon, it's just like there are nuch more people in big cities, but you have usually less friends than people living in small towns...

Comment: But that's partly due to cities being organized in an atomized way which doesn't encourage forming closer interpersonal bonds. The question is whether SO has a "refraing from voting on questions" culture.

Answer (score 1):

*Content is King*<sup>(TM)</sup>.

On average, good<sup>1</sup> questions will receive upvotes and bad<sup>2</sup> questions will receive downvotes.

While SO has a huge number of users, this does not necessarily mean that every good question will receive an upvote and that every bad question will receive a downvote.

However, this also means it is unlikely that "on average" good questions are not being upvoted.

<sub>1. defined as at least one standard deviation in the right direction from the mean<sup>3</sup>.

2. defined as at least one standard deviation in the wrong direction from the mean.

3. defined per tag cluster, you'll notice some tags have wildly different ideas of 'average'.</sub>

Comment: I wonder if a skilled [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) user could determine how many highly-upvoted questions (say, 10+) SO gets per day compared to TeX.

Comment: SO probably gets more bike sheds than TeX does. Beyond +5ish you no longer can tell if the question is actually any good from votes alone.

Comment: True, but many of the easy questions already have answers, and we're getting pretty good about whacking new dupes.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Different tags are a bit different with respect to dups, some are more aggressive about closing, some end up answering the question repeatedly (or at least have more people answer the dup before it can be closed).

Comment: @user7116: So what you're saying, is that 68% (Normal distribution function integrated over -1 to +1) of questions should not / do not get any votes - despite being average questions. Is this a good thing?

Comment: @einpoklum: why do you think the average should be >0?

Comment: @user7116: I think that should not be a principle, just a consequence of other principles. First, many/most questions with negative votes should be corrected or closed. Second, questions with no votes at all should be voted for by someone who has 'vetted' them as reasonable, worthwhile questions.

Comment: @einpoklum: why? All you're doing is diluting the usage of the question "score". An average question should have a 0 (you can have an average question which should not be closed AND should not have up or down votes). An above average question should be >0, and a below average question should be <0. (re: "why not make 10 louder?")

Comment: @user7116: An average question should _not_, in my opinion, have a score of 0. That makes it indistinguishable from a question nobody's bothered to read through and consider. I'd say an average question, after a short while, should have a low score, greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think if a question is helpful for other users, it will get its share of upvotes.  I've come across many questions that have.  I don't know about the TeX site, and I've never seen it come up in a Google search but when I first became a user here it was because it came up near the top of every search I did.  I would suspect there are more "inexperienced" users here because of that phenomenon, and most newer users don't really understand the voting system.  Similarly, I've seen many questions get great answers, the "asker" posts a comment that says, "WOW!  Awesome answer, this helped so much!", yet they never upvote or checkmark the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's frustrating when your reputation is not that high... and you feel awkward adding a comment saying "so please upvote me then" because it makes you sound greedy.

Comment: But... I don't think the evidence supports your assumption that worthwhile questions get their share of upvotes. What's more, questions themselves are not supposed to be *helpful*, just, well, "poignant" would be the adjective I guess.

Comment: Wrong, on both counts.  First, you shouldn't ask for upvotes.  In fact, I think that's actually against the rules.  Second, questions CAN be helpful.  If I ask "How do I format a date in Access?" and you also need to know the answer, then the question is helpful to you and you should upvote it.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that in your view, question votes should essentially mean "I'm also interested in knowing the answer to this question", but not "this question is well-put/thought-provoking/etc."?

Comment: I think they can mean both.  I tend to only upvote questions that I can also gain knowledge from.  I don't go looking through Android questions trying to find well-thought-out questions, because I really could care less about Android.  But I do go through C# questions trying to find ones that I also have questions about, and I'll upvote those.

Comment: What knowledge would you gain from reading a question, rather than an answer?

Comment: If it gets an answer, I gain knowledge.